# Python - Accessing parent members

Tags: python, class, import, namespaces, member

I'm facing a standstill here while trying to figure out how to have member classes access data from their parent when they are part of an external module.

Basically, this works (the B class can access is parent's methods like so:  A.say_hi(A) ):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initializing parent object...")
        self.child = self.B()

    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            print("Initializing child...")
            A.say_hi(A)

    def say_hi(self):
        print("A class says hi")
```

However, this can get pretty messy if classes start getting extra large, so I have been placing my additional classes in files and importing them inline. The problem with that is I can no longer get the member class to access its parent's members and functions if I try to use 'import B.py' when class B is defined within.

Is there any way to get the original behavior without leaving the member class inside the same file as the parent?

Comment: what python version are you using? in 2.7 it doesn't work, as you're passing A (class) where A instance is expected

Comment: Is your indentation correct?  It doesn't appear to be.  "the B class can access is parent's methods like so: A.say_hi(A)" doesn't make any sense at all.  Since the `A.say_hi(A)` is very, very peculiar Python.  Are you confused about inheritance?  Is that your question?

Comment: @soulcheck it works in py3k, (with indentation as in the post)

Answer (score 3):

Actually in your example you couldn't access instance of A in your class B. And the code `A.say_hi(A)` does work however is wrong. This has been said in comments to your question.

Here is how you do that if you want to be able to access parent instance:

Module `b`:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def say_hi(self):
        print 'Child says hi to his parent %s' % (
            self.parent.__class__.__name__
        )
        self.parent.say_hi()
```

Module `a`:

```
from b import B

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B(self)

    def say_hi(self):
        print 'Parent says hi!'
```

Comment: He can access "A" from "B" in his code, due to a side-effect: the class A will be available in the module global name space when functions in B are finally called, from an instance of "A".

Comment: Can access class A, but not the instance of A, this is the important difference. If not circular imports it would be as easy to access class A in module b, just import a and you have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the object (a) to the class (b), you can call it directly.

```
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        print"Made A"

    def test(self):
        print ">>A Test"

class b():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        print"Made B"
        self.parent = parent        
    def test(self):
        print ">>B Test"
        self.parent.test()

a = a()
a.test()
b = b(a)        
b.test()
```